# Discover Android devices by using Bonjour

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bonjour

is it possible to discover android devices over wifi/3g by using Bonjur on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Bonjour is for iOS devices and Mac OS X only. (It can additionally be installed on Windows, but it's not supported on Android.)

Comment: as i understand there is no way/api to connect android and ios devices over wifi/3g ?

Comment: @taffarel you don't need fancy APIs; any two Internet-capable device on the same LAN can connect to each other using BSD sockets,

Answer (score 3):

I think it was a bit irritating. Actually the bonjour service exist before apple release it.

It is called jmdns ([More Infos here](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net)).

and you can check the android version here:
[androidjmdns](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html)

It is fully compatible between ios and android

Answer (score 1):

There is an app in the Google Play Store, Android NAS, that I've been using to have my phone's external storage showup as a Bonjour device. You can even change the icon you want to show up. I'm guessing there's still some development issues because it's a little buggy but it usually works well.